# How to map a stored procedure with a constant property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, mapping, entity-framework-6

I've tried to map a stored procedure:

```
MapToStoredProcedures(t =>
                t.Update(u =>
                    u.HasName("UpdatePerson","dbo")
                        .Parameter(v => v.PersonId, "PersonId")
                        .Parameter(v => v.Cellphone, "Cellphone")
                        .Parameter(v => v.Telephone, "Telephone")
                        .Parameter(v => v.Email, "Email")
                        .Parameter(v => v.LogUserId, "LogUserId")));
```

But I need `LogUserId` be a const property, but when I declare it as:

```
public int LogUserID { { get { return 1;} }
```

returning the value I want, it doesn't work.

How can I pass this value in mapping as a constant?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this question I used the LogUserId as an int in the class, and didn't explicit mapping for it. So I used the mapping to procedure exactly the same, but without a map to the property:

```
Property(t => t.PersonId).HasColumnName("PersonId");
            Property(t => t.Cellphone).HasColumnName("Cellphone");
            Property(t => t.Telephone).HasColumnName("Telephone");
            Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnName("Email");

            MapToStoredProcedures(t =>
                t.Update(u =>
                    u.HasName("UpdatePerson", "dbo")
                        .Parameter(v => v.PersonId, "PersonId")
                        .Parameter(v => v.Cellphone, "Cellphone")
                        .Parameter(v => v.Telephone, "Telephone")
                        .Parameter(v => v.Email, "Email")
                        .Parameter(v => v.LogUserId, "LogUserId")
                        ));
```